# IDA - Best way to find out type of function parameters?

Tags: ida

This is probably a stupid question.

Imagine our dissassembled function takes 1 parameter, for example "unsigned short *"

However, in c++ this could be a BSTR, or something else...what is the best way to figure out the type of input that is expected?

Right now I am just making educated guesses..but there must be a better way? (Or if someone can point me to good books/resources covering this)

Comment: Do a web search for "reverse engineering type inference"

Comment: I was about to recommend you "do an educated guess", until I read this is what you do. This is what, personally, I do. There is no other way, I think. You need to reverse engineer a number of callees and callers to determine its type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To figure out the type of a function parameter, you could reverse engineer the caller to see where the input parameter is coming from and how it's instantiated (potentially needing to go up a few levels in the call stack), and/or you could reverse engineer the callee to see how it handles the parameter.